# Download mailbox using Email Audit API

Tags: google-api, google-email-audit-api

I am trying to download mailbox of a user. For this, firstly i generated public key and then uploaded that to domain. Then try to  download user's mailbox..But it is taking much time to download even if that user have 5 to 10 mails....When i downloaded the mail box, i got a request ID for that mailbox and when i am trying to get status of this request ID mailbox, it give pending......So please give me suggestion...

Comment: I think you have mistagged the question. I Don't think GAS is involved here. please retag with Google Email Audit API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer
I got completed status after some hours and also got a download URL to download mailbox...When i hit that url, a file is download on my machine....

Email Audit Api takes some time to process request.....

Comment: But i was doing this by AOuth playground...But when i tried to run this code via google script then some time it executes and sometime it gives arror error of timeout...